# Can you use TinyMCE commands in a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, tinymce

I want to add text to TinyMCE editor if my Chrome Extension content script detects that one exists. So rather than type text you could insert specific text programatically.

Note: I do not want to use TinyMCE *IN* my Chrome Extension.

It would seem that, since the page my code is injected into has TinyMCE initialized (or at least uses the tinyMCE JS library) that I might be able use the TinyMCE commands in my content script...

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand( 'mceInsertContent', false, 'Some default Text' );
```

Of course this gets rejected because TinyMCE isn't initialized or available.

Any guidance or other approaches to try? Or would I have to build a plugin for TinyMCE or similar?

Comment: Content script's javascript environment is fully isolated from the page so you need to [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: Thank you...so would it be possible to init tinyMCE if you insert code in this way? Or another route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick was to put:

```
"match_about_blank": true
```

in the content_scripts section of the manifest...then the content script is added to every iframe, even ones from other domains, and you can access the body and other tags - even in mce editor.